# Android Studio Emulator Not Working on Mac

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am new to the site as well as to programming in Android Studio. However, I learnt how to use it, but as it's still a new thing, I got stuck when I tried running the app on my Mac. It is a 2015 Mac with 8 GB RAM. This is the message displayed when trying to run the app. Can anyone please help me?

[Screenshot of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wtSB.png)

Comment: welcome to SO. please don't post links to images, include your resources in your question

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, but it doesn't allow me to post the image directly. The code I wrote in Android Studio is small and I checked - it doesn't have errors. But when I get to running it, it's a different story. I tried uninstalling and installing again the Emulator but to no avail.

Comment: This file is present on my system. Your Mac specs are fine for Android Studio. Perhaps try uninstall and reinstall `Android Emulator` using the `SDK Manager`? After that, in 'AVD Manager', create a new AVD and try launch directly from there. Then try running your android project in that AVD.

Comment: I saw somewhere that maybe I need to update my operating system to a newer one. Someone said that from El Capitan 10.12 onwards ( I have 10.11.6 ), it should work fine. I'll try that and then post my results. But thank you anyways for the suggestion RandomThoughts2468! I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Ok, so I found out the problem. Indeed, the operating system needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found out the problem. Indeed, the operating system needs to be updated.